# Is there a way to put a Pdf inside a Swal modal?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, modal-dialog, sweetalert2

I'am making a button to when te user click, open up a Swal... the thing is, how can I put a Pdf view inside that swal modal, without send the user to another page?

It's possible to do that using the Sweet Alert library? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some html code inside SweetAlert.

```
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  icon: 'info',
  html:
    'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
    '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
    'and other HTML tags',
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  focusConfirm: false,
  confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
  cancelButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
  cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down'
})
```

And then try to add your pdf with embed, for exemple:

```
<embed src="files/Brochure.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

References:

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

https://www.codexworld.com/embed-pdf-document-file-in-html-web-page/